# Show that T is a linear transformation and find a, b, c

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, polynomials, transformation

I'm having trouble understanding this question and the proper way to solve it.
I don't understand the solution given and why this was the right way to answer it.

---

### Problem:

For the vector space $P_3$ of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3, let $T:P_3 \rightarrow R$ be the function

$$T(p)=p(2)+p(3)$$

Show that $T$ is a linear transformation, and find numbers a, b, and c so that

$$T(x+a)=T(x^2+b)=T(x^3+c)=0$$

---

### Solution:

\begin{align*}
T(p+q) &= (p+q)(2)+(p+q)(3) \\
&= \left(p(2)+q(2)\right)+\left(p(3)+q(3)\right)\\
&= \left(p(2)+p(3)\right)+\left(q(2)+q(3)\right)\\
&= T(p)+T(q) \\\\
T(cp) &= (cp)(2) +(cp)(3) \\
&= c\left(p(2)\right) + c\left(p(3)\right) \\
&= c\left(p(2)+p(3)\right) \\
&= cT(p)
\end{align*}
Because of these proofs $T$ **is** a linear transformation.
\begin{align*}
T(x+a)&=(2+a)+(3+a)\\
&=2a+5\\
&=0 \\\\
a&=-\frac{5}{2}\\\\
&...\\\\
b&=-\frac{13}{2}\\\\
c&=-\frac{35}{2}
\end{align*}

---

### My Confusion:

- What is "$T:P_3\rightarrow R$" in words?
- What is $P_3$ and how does it relate to the problem?
- What does the lowercase $p$ in $T(p)=p(2)+p(3)$ represent and why can you replace it?
- How does $\left(p(2)+p(3)\right)+\left(q(2)+q(3)\right)= T(p)+T(q)$? 
  or $c\left(p(2)+p(3)\right)= cT(p)$?
- Why isn't it intuitive that $T(p)=p(2)+p(3)$ is a transformation?

Answer (score 3):

Answers:

When $\;V_{\Bbb F}\;$ is a vector space over a field $\;\Bbb F\;$ , a linear transformation $\;T:V\to \Bbb F\;$ is called *A linear functional* .

$\;P_n\;$ is the vector space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal $\;n\;$ with coefficients from some field. Its dimension is $\;n+1\;$

$\;p\;$ represents a polynomial in $\;P_3\;$ .

The next question has an obvious answer if you've understood so far what's going on here.

I've no idea why you think such a thing is/would be "obvious", "intuitive" or whatever. This is mathematics and stuff must be proved. Period.